# How to search and replace with sed, but with a number after the first matching group (proper escaping of matching group)

Tags: sed

### Preamble

Maybe you want to convert this:

```
aaaa
```

To:

```
1aaa1
```

So let's propose this:

```
echo aaaa | sed --regexp-extended 's/(.*)a/1\11/'
→
1aaa1
```

### Question

Is `1\11` a 100% valid unambiguous `sed` pattern? Am I complying with all `sed` good practice with such replacement?

I mean that `1\11` *maybe* could be both of these:

1. replace with char `1`, then the 1° matched group, then another char `1` (→ current behavior)
2. replace with char `1`, then the **11**° matched group (→ causing an exception)

At the moment it seems my sed version has the first interpretation. Anyway I don't know if this is documented or if it can be wrote in a better way in `sed`.

Thank you for any clarification. In the meanwhile I will not build a castle on this.

At the moment I'm using GNU sed 4.7.

Comment: Related about numbered backreferences: https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [description in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) that reads:

> The back-reference expression '\n' shall match the same (possibly empty) string of characters as was matched by a subexpression enclosed between "(" and ")" preceding the '\n'. The character 'n' shall be a digit from 1 through 9, specifying the nth subexpression (the one that begins with the nth "(" from the beginning of the pattern and ends with the corresponding paired ")" ).

Which will avoid any `\10` or `\11`.

That's the syntax for BRE, but we do not need to worry about ERE in POSIX as those do not allow backreferences.

The Manual for GNU sed states the same. I do not believe there is any sed that allows more than `\1...\9` backreferences.

Also, the right side of a replacement `s///` may contain references to capture parentheses. Those are [not clearly delimited in Posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html):

> The characters "\n", where n is a digit, shall be replaced by the text matched by the corresponding back-reference expression.

But it seems to be using the same rule as for back-references.

GNU sed does state that clearly:

> Back-references are specified with backslash and a single digit (e.g.  '\1').

One language that allows more backreferences is Perl. But in that language, backreferences with more than one digit are written `${23}`. I imagine that such a provision, or similar, is generally used to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 2):

As said by the user @QuartzCristal, in the GNU's `sed` man page there is this note:

> s/regexp/replacement/
>
> Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.  The replacement may contain the special character &
> to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the  reg‐
> exp.

Coming from generic programming languages (like Perl) where there is no such limitation from `1` to `9` (since for example you can write `1{$19}1`), I was not aware of this limitation in `sed`. So, I understand that at the moment the syntax is just 100% correct and cannot be onterpreted in no other way.

This answer is valid for GNU sed. Not sure it's a POSIX definition.

Comment: One language that allows for backreferences is Perl. But such references are actually written `${16}`. So, no expectations of confusion.

Comment: That's exactly the syntax that I was not finding in `sed`. Good to know that there is a reason for this lack. I'm integrating in the answer.

Comment: Note that perl can also happily handle `$11`, it just _also_ supports `${11}` to avoid ambiguity. So `echo abcdefghijklmn | perl -lpe 's/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.).*/$11/'` works, but `echo abcdefghijklmn | perl -lpe 's/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.).*/$111/'` fails and requires `echo abcdefghijklmn | perl -lpe 's/(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.).*/${11}1/'`